# NodeMCU access point for MQTT broker

Tags: nodemcu

Is it possible to publish and subscribe using MQTT, when the mqtt broker is connected to a network which is created by a NodeMCU?

Can a NodeMCU connect to its own created network?

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). You already [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46789341).

Comment: no, there's no broker that runs on arduino.

Answer (score 1):

The devices conected via an NodeMCU acting as an WiFi Access Point can communicate between with the NodeMCU and between themselves.

So, if all devices involved are connected to the same NodeMCU, then they can communicate as you asked.

NodeMCU also works as an Access Point + Station. Beside being an AP, then NodeMCU can simultaneously be a client in another WiFi network.

I doubt NodeMCU can route between his client and the external WiFi network.